# Can I make a script to prevent mouse bounce clicks?

Tags: mouse, button, xev

Recently my mouse has started bounce clicking, single clicks act as double and even tipple clicks most if the time. Holding left click tends to spam click and trying to do anything has become increasingly difficult if I wish to use my external mouse. I have come to the understanding that it is indeed my mouse and not my operating system due to the fact that the mouse is old and beat up.

Holding click spams the following (In terminal I used '`xev | grep Button`' to return the following output.)

```
ButtonPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
ButtonRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
```

Windows has a function built in to prevent bounce clicks, I was wondering if there was a way to do this in linux before I go out and buy a new mouse.

Comment: 6 years and still nobody can do this, it seems. It's funny if you search for it, people only care to disable it and magically they have it somehow